# Displaying Custom Sidebar Without Modifying Theme's Core File?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, sidebar, register-sidebar

Is there a way to display custom sidebar created with a plugin on the wordpress front-end without modifying theme's core file?

EDIT:

Here is what I currently doing:

I hooked the custom dynamic sidebar to `get_sidebar` and the sidebar is go to the bottom of the sidebar area.

```
add_action('get_sidebar', 'this_callback');

function this_callback(){
dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-8' );
}
```

Comment: Sidebars are theme territory, not plugins. `get_sidebar` is an action, not a filter. Thinking about it, why would you replace one sidebar with another in the same position?

Comment: I just want to know how this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-sidebars/ displaying its custom sidebars...